# Fiori : Could not open App, target was not found

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-gateway, s4hana

I have activated the apps 'My Work Queue and Assign Work', and when i click on the apps i got the error "Target was not found"

(adding element with duplicate id)

I have activated the ICF nodes and the ODATA services as well as the role assignment. I have succesfully implemented the other applications but only those 2 are not working.

Could anyone help me fix this problem ?

Best regards

[image]

Comment: Were you able to open a support incident? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73922395/5846045

Answer (score 1):

This is a coding issue in the frontend application. Create a support incident (Cf. [SAP KBA 1296527](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0001296527)). The support component should be PP-PEO-SFE according to ["My Work Queue" reference page](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F3499%27)/S23OP).

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, open your development tool and see in console and network tab is there is any dependent backend service which is required to enable along with them.